Is it possible to embed a Power BI report without using an iframe?
I have a requirement to embed a Power BI report ("Embed for your Customers") into a website without using an iframe. I referred to the following article and GitHub code, but the solution still embeds the report using an iframe:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal?tabs=azure-portal
I would like to know if there is any way to embed a Power BI report directly into a website without using an iframe. Are there any alternative approaches or documentation that I can follow to achieve this?
I followed the steps mentioned in the article linked above and successfully embedded the report using .NET Core and .NET Framework. However, the report is being loaded within an iframe, which I want to avoid.
Is there any possibility of embedding a Power BI report without relying on an iframe?

No, It's not possible. iframe is definitely used to embed Power BI Artifact into an website.
